# how to visualize the graph use matplotlib on polynomial and multiple regression with multiple predictors

Tags: data-visualization, polynomial, matplotlib

## Multiple: y=b0+b1X1+b2X2+b3X3....bnXn

## Polynomial: y=b0+b1X+b2(X)^2+....bn(X)^n

## Step1: Importing package

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels

## Step2; Read data using pandas

dataset = pd.read_csv('ordor.csv',delimiter='\t')
X=dataset.iloc[:,1:4].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,0].values

## Step 3: Preprocessing of data: Not Required as there is no categorical data in this dataset

## Step 4: Splitting of data into train and test set: Not required as total populationsize is very small (15,4)

## step 5: Multiple Linear Regression Classifier.

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
l=LinearRegression()
l.fit(X,y)
y_pred=l.predict(X)

## Step 6: Polynomial Linear Regression Classifier

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
P=PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_poly=P.fit_transform(X)
Pl=LinearRegression()
Pl.fit(X_poly,y)
py_pred=Pl.predict(X_poly)

## Visualize the Multiple Regression and Polynomial Regression

plt.scatter(X,y,color='green')
plt.plot(X,y_pred,color='blue')
plt.title('Multple LR')
plt.xlabel('Temp,Ratio,Height')
plt.ylabel('Odor')
plt.show()

plt.scatter(X,y, color='red')
plt.plot(X,py_pred,color='blue')
plt.title('Polynomial LR')
plt.xlabel('Temp,Ratio,Height')
plt.ylabel('Odor')
plt.show()